# Pass Associative Array from Symfony Controller to Twig and JavaScript

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

So, I have 2 arrays that I've combined into one array after making sure they're the same length as such.

```
//Fetching Ratings for All Coaches & Making a Key, Value Associative Array with Coach id as Key and Rating as Value
        $coaches = $coachRepository->findAll();
        $rating = $coachRepository->findRatingByCoach();
        //Array of coach IDs
        $id_array = array();
        foreach ($coaches as $c){
            $id_array[] = $c->getId();
        }
        $combined = array_combine($id_array, $rating);
```

Now I want to pass this key, value array to Twig template and JavaScript. I'm currently doing this

```
    return $this->render('...', [
        ..., 'combined'=>$combined
    ]);
```

And I'm accessing the array in Twig as such

```
            {% for key, value in combined %}
                {{ key }} - {{ value }}
            {% endfor %}
```

And I'm getting this error.

```
Object of class App\Entity\Coach could not be converted to string
```

Looking at the Stack Trace I can see that the array combined is being passed in this form.

```
'combined' => array(object(Coach))
```

After a bit of debugging it turns out that I thought the issue was with the $`id_array` when in fact it's the $`rating` variable that's presenting an issue. I'm not sure why but I'm getting a single float value.
I fixed the issue by changing how I'm fetching the $rating, now instead of using a QueryBuilder to get it from the DB, I'm getting it from list of Coaches as such

```
 //Array of coach IDs and array of Ratings
        $id_array = array();
        $rating_array = array();
        foreach ($coaches as $c){
            $id_array[] = $c->getId();
            $rating_array [] = $c->getRating();
        }
```

Even if I set the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging it turns out that I thought the issue was with the $id_array when in fact it's the $rating variable that's presenting an issue. I'm not sure why but I'm getting a single float value. I fixed the issue by changing how I'm fetching the $rating, now instead of using a QueryBuilder to get it from the DB, I'm getting it from list of Coaches as such

```
    //Fetching Ratings for All Coaches & Making a Key, Value Associative Array with Coach as Key and Rating as Value
    $coaches = $coachRepository->findAll();
    //Array of coach IDs and array of Ratings
    $id_array = array();
    $rating_array = array();
    foreach ($coaches as $c){
        $id_array[] = $c->getId();
        $rating_array []= $c->getRating();
    }
    $this->debug_to_console($id_array[0]);
    $combined = array_combine($id_array, $rating_array);
```

I'm still accessing the array in the same way in twig